# Bring back mouseover-to-show tabs in fullscreen Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, fullscreen

I remember chrome used to show the tabs even in full-screen mode if you mouse-over the top of the screen. That doesn't seem to work anymore and all I get when I mouse-over the top of the screen is an X button that exits full-screen mode. Is there a flag or something that brings back this feature?

I know about ctrl-tab as well as ctrl-shift-A, however ctrl-tab doesn't give you a visual sense of your tabs, and ctrl-shift-A doesn't give you a spatial sense of your tabs (because the order of the tabs in that view change based on recency of access)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Try the extension [Tab & URL manager](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/tab-url-manager/egiemoacchfofdhhlfhkdcacgaopncmi?pli=1).